# Can't install tensorflow using pip version 20, no versions found?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, installation

I am running a python code for which I need tensorflow 2.0, but when running *pip install tensorflow* (or pip3), I get the following error:

**Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow**

I checked the tensorflow website and I'm running python version 3.7, so I tried the wheel they suggested for Windows 64-bit, CPU-only (https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) but I get the following error now:

**ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.**

My system's properties are below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r7ja.png)

Any idea what the issue could be? Thanks!

Comment: try `pip install tensorflow==2.1.0`

Comment: Are you looking to install tensorflow version 2.0 ?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I need at least version 2.0. Unfortunately specifying the version doesn't work because it doesn't find any version.

Comment: Error message: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorrflow==2.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorrflow==2.1.0

Comment: I would highly recommend using anaconda.

Comment: This might help you  https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this is a git project I am working on with other people and I can't use anaconda in this case.

Comment: About the tensorflow website, I already followed their instructions and to the same result

Comment: Run `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"`, what output do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow requires 64-bit Python, your Python is 32-bit. Install 64-bit Python.

TensorFlow currently support Python up to 3.7 so do not install Python 3.8. Install 64-bit Python 3.7.

Comment: Funny thing, I checked this and thought it was 64 bit. But I indeed installed the 32-bit Python version by mistake. Many thanks!